# Showing equivalence between the Jordan Curve Theorem and another similar theorem.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, geometric-topology

In Rolfsen's Knots and Links there is an exercise to show the equivlance between the the JCT and another theorem:

1. JCT: If $J$ is a simple closed curve in $R^2$, then $R^2-J$ has two components, and $J$ is the boundary of each.
2. TH: If $L$ is a closed subset of $R^2$ which is homeomorphic with $R^1$, then $R^2-L$ has two components, and $L$ is the boundary of each.

I understand that $L$ can't be bounded, else it will be compact and not homeomorphic to $R^1$. Also $L$ is not homeomorphic to $J$ since removing a point from $R^1$ leaves it disconnected but not $J$. Kindly provide hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Have you learned about the one-point compactification?

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment, they both become statements about loops on $\mathbb{S}^2.$ In particular, it is important that $L$ is unbounded on both ends (which is equivalent to saying it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}.$)

Comment: @LeeMosher I had earlier but I'll have to revise it. Is it trivial or would it need the application of another big theorem?

Comment: @MandelBroccoli Could you please elaborate? I am only familiar with the definition of one point compactification.

Comment: Since $L$ is a plane curve that is unbounded on both ends, then $L$ can be completed as a closed curve in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ which is $\mathbb{S}^2.$ Similarly, a bounded closed curve $J$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ stays a closed curve in the one-point compactification, $\mathbb{S}^2.$ Therefore, they are both statements about closed curves on $\mathbb{S}^2.$ This doesn't quite prove their equivalence, but it's quite close.